# Creating an appointment with RequiredAttendees external to domain

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS to create appointments with multiple attendees. I need to add both local (in our Exchange-domain) and external attendees. It works for local users but external users are not receiving the invitation, although the email is shown in the appointment in Outlook. Is this a setting in Exchange or am I doing something wrong?

When I open the appointment in Outlook it says that invites were not sent. If I then click send in Outlook, the invite is sent.

This is my code:

```
     ExchangeService _service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);

     _service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(username, password);
     _service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
     _service.Url = new Uri(exchangeClientConfig.ExchangeServiceUrl);
     _service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, email);

    Appointment appointment = new Appointment(_service);

    appointment.Subject = subject;
    appointment.Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.Text, text);
    appointment.Start = dateTimeStart;
    appointment.End = dateTimeStart.AddHours(durationClock.Hour).AddMinutes(durationClock.Minut);
    appointment.RequiredAttendees.Add(to);

    appointment = (Appointment)LoadExtendedProperties(appointment, recnum);

    appointment.Save(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, SendInvitationsMode.SendOnlyToAll);
```

Comment: Can you show us the code used to add attendees to the appointment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have to specify a location. Once I did this, the invitations are sent to external attendees too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, strange as it is.
Is the location anywhere or a Room Mailbox?

Comment: Anywhere. I just put in a'random' hardcoded string to test it and that made it work.